# SVG templates, best place to put them for reuse, internal, external?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an app in which the user can put svg pictures on to the screen.  These pictures are from a predefined library that is given to the user.  The library will have about 20 pictures (which are not big files size) in but may grow over time.

The workflow for the user is they click a button and they get an svg to place.

At the moment there is a div in the page which is styled to display none.  In that div there is a "template" of each of the svgs (the full inline code), so when the user clicks a button it clones the relevant template for them to use.

It works fine, but it seems perhaps not the best methodology since all 20 templates are always loaded, even though the user may use 0.

So my question..baring in mind the user may use 0 templates, or may use every template several times, performance wise whats the best methodology, i can think of a couple of ways...

1. use the current template in the html, but this means that the svgs
   are always in the dom
2. have each svg as a seperate file, but then it
   will have to go get it from the server everytime the user wants the
   template
3. potentially (though im not sure this would work) have it in the css as a background image so I would just be applying the relevant class
4. store all the svgs as varaibles in my JS

Ultimatley im not even sure theres much in this as the svgs are not complex i just dont like the idea of having to have all the templates in the DOM all the time, if anyone could suggest a logical approach I would appriciate it

Comment: Maybe what you should do is to take a look at what are doing the others, for example https://css-tricks.com/.  If you open the page in view-source you'll see the svg elements with the defs and the symbols at the bottom at the page, just before the scripts.

Comment: but they arnt dyncamically adding svgs over and over again as I will be, their svgs are just for page content

Comment: In this case you may need to save those svg in a data base

Answer (score 0):

I would take the middle street and I would have each template in its own file on the server. During deployment, I would fusionate them into a single file, but I would wait for the user to use one of the templates to download that file with all the templates, gzipped, of course.

Take into account that this has a limit. As the library grows, there will be a moment when the download time will be unacceptable. In order to solve it, simply divide those SVGs into bundles, fusionate them in their respective files and download each of them on demand.